# Mapping columnvalue as property in .net core

Tags: .net-core

I have a certain api that has output as below:

```
       [
         {
            "placeholder": "SIGN_IN",
            "value": "Sign In"
         }
         ....
       ]
```

I need the output to be like below in order to use it for the ngrx-translation:

```
     ["SIGN_IN": "Sign_In", ....]
```

I do not want to do this mapping on the client side, rather directly from the API itself

Comment: the format of Required out put is not possible check that u need `{"SIGN_IN": "Sign_In", ....}`